# How to return number from JSON string?

Tags: sql, regex, exasolution

I would like to pull the **13 digit** number from this JSON string:

{"timeline":{"events":[]},"ongoingSLAData":null,"completeSLAData":[],"metricId":1024,"definitionChangeDate":**1498910425180**,.........

Is it possible using SQL to pull this number out, convert it to an INT and use it as a variable in some calculation?

I have tried REGEX, Functions in Exasol (Database) but cant wrap my head around it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `(?<=definitionChangeDate":)(\d*)` [regex](https://regex101.com/r/kMTYIK/1) ?

Comment: Cool, thanks -  so that pulls the number out but how could i store it as an INT variable and use it in a calculation? Could i CAST it as an INT and then use it in my calculation?